# What is the origin of the adjective "peaked" (pronounced "pea-ked"), meaning "tired" in American English?

Tags: etymology, american-english, pronunciation, suffixes, north-american-english

I was watching the movie "In the Line of Fire" (1993) with Clint Eastwood and Rene Russo. In one of the scenes, Russo tells Eastwood, "you were looking a little pea-ked out there", meaning tired/fatigued/physically overwhelmed.

That's the only usage I've found of the term, and Google lists this as a North American usage. Where did it come from, and why is it pronounced that way?

Comment: Interesting. The Oxford English Dictionary only transcribes a monsyllabic pronunciation, but some of the citations it gives seem to provide evidence of the disyllabic pronunciation: "He looks peakeder than ever," "It seemed as if my aunt might have gone on for ever, getting a little dryer and her face more peakit"

Comment: It came from the past tense of the nearly-obsolete meaning of the verb [*peak*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peak): *to grow thin and sickly; to dwindle away*. And like *blessed, ragged, aged, learned*, the two-syllable pronunciation from Early Modern English hasn't entirely died out (although it apparently has in the U.K.)

Comment: In the UK, it's more common to use "peaky", as in: "you're looking a bit peaky".

Comment: @calum_b I'd say *peaky* means a little ill, while *peaked* is more like physically exhausted. But that could be sampling error on my part as I don't hear either very often, and they're obviously very close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its usage is from   the early 1800s and refers to peaked meaning "sickly-looking". The pronounciation in two distinct syllables is common  in AmE.

> - ***[“Peaked”](http://www.word-detective.com/2011/01/peaked/)*** with the connotation you are referring to didn’t appear until the early 19th century and was originally a regional colloquial term in Britain. ***The full definition in the OED, to which I alluded earlier, gives a clue to the logic of this “peaked”: “Sharp-featured, thin, pinched, as from illness or undernourishment; sickly looking.***”
> - ***We refer to a sickly-looking person as “peaked” because illness frequently causes weight loss and a haggard, wasted appearance resulting in “sharp” (i.e., bony) facial features, making the nose, chin, etc., appear to end in sharp points*** (“It seemed as if my aunt might have gone on for ever, getting a little dryer and her face more peakit, as the years went by,” 1914). Lack of proper nutrition can, of course, also lead to a “peaked” appearance, so advanced age or serious illness are not prerequisites for being “peaked” (“The children looked peaked and unhealthy,” 1992). In general use, in fact, a person exhibiting nothing more than a sickly demeanor or a bilious aura is also often described as “peaked” (“Bill looked a bit peaked after his third helping of clams”).
> - So while this “peaked” doesn’t mean that you’re having your best day ever, there are “peaks” involved. ***Incidentally, this “peaked” is, in the US, frequently pronounced in two distinct syllables (“peek-ed”), which is handy when your pal says “I’m peaked” and you’re not sure whether he means that he’s on top of the world or at death’s door.***

(The Word Detective)